# Conditionally Override Default PK Sequence in Single Insert

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

Say I have table customer2 defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE customer2(
  customer_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(('customer.customer_identity'::text)::regclass),
  customer_name character varying
CONSTRAINT customer2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
)
```

I have another table called customer1 with the same table definition.  Before inserting into customer2 I want to check customer1 to see if a customer_id exists for the same customer_name, and if so use it.  My insert statement looks similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO customer2(
  customer_id,
  customer_name)
SELECT customer_id, --null if not found in customer1 table
       nc.customer_name
  FROM new_customers nc
  LEFT OUTER JOIN customer1 c1 on c1.customer_name = nc.customer_name
```

When running this insert I get the error "null value in column "customer_id" violates not-null constraint".  Is there a way to use the default sequence when I don't have a customer_id to insert?  Obviously I can write two different insert statements, but alas that's significant and seemingly unnecessary code duplication which irks my programming nature.

Comment: Also, I would be very curious if anyone had an idea on how to search the internet for an answer to this question.  Searching for specific and odd situations like this always baffle me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just use a `coalesce` and a `nextval` to just use the sequence when it is null.

```
INSERT INTO customer2(
  coalesce(customer_id, nextval('customer.customer_identity')),
  customer_name)
SELECT customer_id, --null if not found in customer1 table
       nc.customer_name
  FROM new_customers nc
  LEFT OUTER JOIN customer1 c1 on c1.customer_name = nc.customer_name
```